# Add the today and tomorrows date infront of my dates

Tags: javascript, html

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kxqndpk1/2/

```js
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
    'August','September','October','November','December'];       
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());   
    document.getElementById("spanToday").innerHTML = months[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate()+ ", " + today.getFullYear();
    
    
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
    'August','September','October','November','December'];       
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime()  + (1000*3600*24));   
    document.getElementById("spanTomorrow").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

```html
    <span id="spanToday"></span>, at 10:00 AM
    <br>
    <span id="spanTomorrow"></span>, at 10:00 AM
    <br><br>
    Eastern Time (EST)
```

The goal is to add the appropriate day in front of the 2 dates.

Comment: What day do you want to add? The current day?

Comment: what does **appropriate day** means **Monday,Tuesday,etc** or  **1,2..,30**?

Comment: Also why you creating same variable twice..??  `var months = ['January','February',..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getDay()

```js
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
    'August','September','October','November','December'];   
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());   
    document.getElementById("spanToday").innerHTML = days[today.getDay()] + "  " + months[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate()+ ", " + today.getFullYear();
    
     
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime()  + (1000*3600*24));   
    document.getElementById("spanTomorrow").innerHTML =days[tomorrow.getDay()] + "  " + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

```html
<span id="spanToday"></span>, at 10:00 AM
    <br>
    <span id="spanTomorrow"></span>, at 10:00 AM
    <br><br>
    Eastern Time (EST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow similar steps as above for day:

Eg:

```
 var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

now `n` contains day information

Answer (score 0):

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

document.getElementById("spanToday").innerHTML = weekday[today.getDay()] + " " + months[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate()+ ", " + today.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern environment then you can use [The ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) and in particular [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

```js
const now = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date(now.getTime() + 86400000);
const options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
const dateFormater = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options);
const spanToday = document.getElementById('spanToday');
spanToday.textContent = dateFormater.format(now);
const spanTomorrow = document.getElementById('spanTomorrow');
spanTomorrow.textContent = dateFormater.format(tomorrow);
```

```html
<span id="spanToday"></span>, at 10:00 AM
<br>
<span id="spanTomorrow"></span>, at 10:00 AM
<br>
<br> Eastern Time (EST)
```

[There is a polyfill available for older environments.](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/)